# Local Notification message is not coming on device

Tags: iphone

I am working on iPhone application and used local notifications but i would able to receive notifications on simulator but when i am going to test code on device that would not work. In simulator also scheduled notification appeared only if i run code (Build and Run) once after scheduling local notification but checking on device there is no option to run code after scheduling. I am not receiving notification on device.